# Unsigned and/or Long literals with exponent representation

Tags: c++, literals

CPP Reference [describes the format of integral iterals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), however, it doesn't specify all the permutations of base types (hex, binary, octal, exponent, etc.) and data types (unsigned, long, etc.).  So simple question, how would I write `1e9` as an `unsigned long`?  GCC complains with `1e9ul`, which was my first guess.

Comment: You can't.  As the page shows `e` is not part of a integer decimal literal

Comment: seems like you are confusing [floating point literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) with [integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). They are different

Comment: Interesting.  gcc allows using literals such as `1e6` as assignment to integral types without narrowing conversion warnings. Is `1e6` being interpreted as a floating literal and implicitly converted to an integral type?

Comment: @DrTarr compilers have extensions that go beyond what the standard says. In such case you need to study the compilers manual, though for that specific case you would need to show the code. Perhaps that would be a different question

Comment: @DrTarr Since gcc allows using literals such as `1000000.0` as assignment to integral types without narrowing conversion warnings, why would it complain about `1e6`?

Comment: @DrTarr -- to be completely clear: `1e6` **is** a floating-point literal. It is **not** an integer literal. So using it as an initializer for an integer type requires a conversion. Other languages allow this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @pete becker.  I had seen the 1e6 representation before and interpreted it as a integral literal since it lacked the decimal

Comment: What's SO's policy on how to handle an invalid question like this, delete it?

Comment: @DrTarr -- a floating-point literal has **either** a decimal point (with an optional exponent part), **or** a sequence of digits followed by an exponent part. So when there's no decimal point, the exponent part makes it a floating-point literal.